Travelling Sale Man is NP- complete proof
I have some questions about the proof of NP- complteness of travelling saleman. I was watching the video from Prf. Dr. Roughgarden at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyrKqtFsRus. But some part of it confuses me. Here is a picture of the travelling saleman graph and the Hamiltonian graph. The idea of the proof is the simple trivial reduction from Hamiltonain Cycle to TSP.

Here, the magenta graph is our TSP graph. To me what we need is to complete the graph by adding missed edges e.g. add them by green color and give this edges cost of 1, and the rest 0. Then uses trivial reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle to it and check if there is a cycle of cost 0. And the proof is over.
But my problem is that to make a Hamiltionain graph to reduce it to our TSP graph, he augmented the TSP graph (the magenta graph) by adding a vertice V_0. Why he did it? I mean, to me its a redundant action. Why we even need to do this? Is there a reason behind it? I mean, why he made the problem harder by adding a new vertice V_0?
My second question is that in the proof, as you can see in the picture, the cyan edges gets cost 0. Why he gives them cost of 0, considering the fact that they are not in our original TSP graph?
Can some one please explain these two questions for me. Thanks in advance.

Please don't expect people to watch the video to be able to answer: explain the entirety of what is necessary to understand the proof. What is the reduction the author is trying to do? You talk about "the original travelling salesman graph", but that would imply you are trying to do a reduction FROM TSP, and not TO TSP (which would be necessary to prove that TSP is NP-hard).

Also the usual proof is a trivial reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle to TSP, adding a weight $1$ to each edge.

Nathaniel, thanks for your comment. I edited my question so that no one needs to watch the video. And the proof idea is as you said, trivial reduction from Hamiltonain Cycle to TSP. My question is that why he added a vertice to TSP graph to make a Hamiltonian graph? And my problem is that I saw some other videos by other people proving the same problem. They also augment the TSP graph by adding a vertice. My main question is that why we add this edge and do not do the proof without adding that edge? Can you explain?

@Ali.A Your question still makes no sense…

@Nathaniel What do you mean by makes no sense? I asked why we add a vertices (V_0) and then make a Hamiltonaian graph? I mean what if we do not add V_0 to our TSP and have the magenta graph+ the low green edge (so only one green edge). Then Use this graph as our Hamiltonan graph and reduce the Hamiltonian Cycle problem to TSP?

This is a reduction of the Hamiltonian Path (not cycle) problem to the Travelling Salesman cycle (not path) problem. In the version you're describing here, the Travelling Salesman's cycle must start and end at the same place, but that place can be anywhere. The Hamiltonian Path is given a start point $s$ and an endpoint $t$. Without that extra vertex $v_0$, the Travelling Salesman on $G'$ would still reduce to a cycle on $G$, but it would not start at $s$ and end at $t$ (because it starts and ends at the same place).
So we add $v_0$. It's only adjacent to $s$ and $t$, so the salesman necessarily passes through those two edges. Then during the reduction to $G$, we cut the cycle open at that vertex and remove those two edges, and we are left with a single path from $s$ to $t$.
Edit: In fact, on the graph you've posted, there is a Travelling Salesman cycle that costs 0 and visits all the vertices except $v_0$. Start at $s$, go down, diagonally up to $t$, down, and back to $s$. This uses only magenta edges, so it costs 0. And yet there is no Hamiltonian path on $G$ from $s$ to $t$! Problem! So we require the salesman to also visit $v_0$, which rules out this spurious result.
